# State hook not changing boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the code below I am having an issue.

I was trying to implement `doubleClick` behaviors and the state hook for the boolean changes to trigger it. The problem is that even though `handleDoubleClick` function is triggered, `setAllowSingleClick` is not changing the value to false so anyway the `handleClick` function is getting triggered.

```html
<div onClick={handleClick} onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}>
```

```js
const CLICK_DELAY_TIME = 200;
const [allowSingleClick, setAllowSingleClick] = useState(true);
let timer = 0;

const handleClick = () => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (allowSingleClick) {
            doSMTH1();
        }
    }, CLICK_DELAY_TIME);
};

const handleDoubleClick = () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    setAllowSingleClick(false);
    doSMTH();
};
```

Comment: Can you include a more concrete example? Perhaps see [mre] for help.

Comment: I'm asking about things like `doSMTH`, since it could have side-effects causing issues

Comment: This code doesn't make sense since timer is always 0 in clear timeout... It has a closure

Answer (score 1):

do not `useState()` on nested Callbacks. `useRef()` instead.

`useState()` itself is just a kind of hook that returns value and setter(asynchronously works).

when setTimeout() callback function is constructed, the value of allowSingleClick variable is fixed in callback function definition (this phenomenon is known as closure).

what `useRef()` returns itself is object: value evaluated when reference `.current` property.

example code

```js
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const CLICK_DELAY_TIME = 200;
  const allowSingleClickRef = useRef(true);
  const doSMTH1 = () => console.log("!!!");
  const doSMTH = () => console.log("???");
  let timer = null;

  const handleClick = () => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (allowSingleClickRef.current) {
        doSMTH1();
      }
    }, CLICK_DELAY_TIME);
  };

  const handleDoubleClick = () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    allowSingleClickRef.current = false;
    doSMTH();
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

More reading: [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)